# The Naming Conventions of C: A struct and a function

Tags: c, linux

While exploring the facilities for handling system signal requests in the `sigaction.h` header, I noticed that a structure and a function returning an `int` were named `sigaction`.

Even though it seems semantically correct, since the compiler should be able to deduce between the two definitions, why are the duplicate definitions of `sigaction` valid C syntax?

Comment: what's the main reason why this question was down-voted?

Answer (score 7):

In C, struct tags live in a separate namespace from the other names. The struct is called `struct sigaction`, while the function is simply `sigaction`.

Comment: I'd really like to have a comment with that downvote.

Comment: The down vote is not mine, but I think that for a C purist a **namespace** is a kind of an heresy... :-)

Comment: @Frankie_C then the joke is on them, because it's the standard term :p

Comment: @Frankie_C: [Online C2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.2.3 "Name Spaces of Identifiers".

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is able to separate structure tags (also unions and enumerations) because they're following the keywords `struct`/`union`/`enum`, respectively (C11 §6.2.3p1).

Then, declarations are required to be unique within "the same name space", according to §6.7p3.

Since structure tags and function identifiers (which are *ordinary identifiers*) aren't in the same name space, the "clash" is OK.

When it comes to usage, you can't do:

```
typedef struct _test {
    int a;
} test;

void test(void) {

}
```

The compiler will inform you:

```
test.c:5:6: error: 'test' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 void test(void) {
      ^
test.c:3:3: note: previous declaration of 'test' was here
 } test;
```